# If a smooth function $f$ satisfies $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$, all its derivatives are integrable with respect to Gaussian measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

The question is as in the title.

Let $f$ be a smooth function on the real line satisfying $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert$.

Then, it is clear that $f$ itself is integrable with respect to the standard Gaussian measure:
\begin{equation}
d\mu(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} dx.
\end{equation}

However, I am curious about its derivatives, since I would like to perform integration by parts for this function $f$. Could anyone please clarify for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ doesn't really tell us much about $f'(x)$ anywhere except $x=0$, where we must have $|f'(0)| \leq 1$.

For instance, if we consider $\phi_1, \phi_2$ as a partition of unity subordinate to the ordered open cover $(-2,2),\, \mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$, then
$$f(x) = \phi_2(x)\sin(e^{x^2})$$
satisfies

- $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$
- $|f(x)| = 0$ when $|x| \leq 1$
- $|f(x)| \leq 1$
- $|f'(x)|\,d\mu = Cxe^{x^2/2}\cdot|\cos(e^{x^2})|\,dx$ when $x > 2$, which isn't integrable.

Comment: Note that if you don't know about smooth partitions of unity, you could just consider $f(x) = x\sin(e^{x^2})$ to reach the same conclusion, just with a slightly messier derivative.